# 'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Params'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm using **.NET Core 2.0.2** to create an **ASP.NET** webapp in **C#**.

Everytime I use `Request.Url` in my controllers, `dotnet run` outputs an error:

> error CS1061: 'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Url' and no extension method 'Url' accepting a first argument of type 'HttpRequest' could be found

The same thing happens with `Request.Params`. Even though the [.NET documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params(v=vs.110).aspx) says there is a getter for the `Params` property.

I managed to find a workaround for `Request.Url`: I use the `Request.GetUri()` method. However I couldn't find such a replacement for `Request.Params`.

Here are my `using` statements:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using area.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Tweetinvi;
using Tweetinvi.Models;
```

Why am I getting those errors? Do you know a fix? Otherwise, do you have a workaround to get `Request.Params`?

Comment: What specifically are you looking for, from the Params collection ?

Comment: I'm trying to use the Tweetinvi library: https://github.com/linvi/tweetinvi/wiki/Authentication. I'm running the "URL Redirect Authentication" sample code where there is: `Request.Params.Get("oauth_verifier")`. So I want to access `Params`'s `Get()` method

Comment: You can try `Request.Query["oauth_verifier"]`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The stuff you used to get from generic request params is accessible in specific properties of `Request` like `Query`, `Cookies`, `Form` etc.

If you are trying to access a querystring item value, you may use the `Request.Query` property.

```
var v = Request.Query["oauth_verifier"];
```

You can use the `TryGetValue` method on the collection to get the value if it exist.

```
if (Request.Query.TryGetValue("oauth_verifier",out StringValues val))
{
    var theValue = val[0];
    var orUseThis = val.ToString();
    // Use theValue as needed
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`HttpRequest` class is defined (in different ways) in `System.Web` and in `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` namespaces. The former has `Params` property the latter doesn't. Debug to find what kind `HttpRequest` you have (and add proper `using...`).

Answer (score 2):

`HttpRequest.Params` are collection of (`QueryString`, `Form` and `Cookies`) so you can get them:

```
HttpContext.Request.Cookies;
HttpContext.Request.QueryString;
HttpContext.Request.Form;
```

[HttpRequest.Params Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.params%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: As I said in my question, I know I should be able to get `Request.Params` considering that the documentation says it has a getter. But I can't... As explained above, I get the error CS1061.

Answer (score 1):

```
var allParams = Request.Query.Concat(Request.Form);
```

If you want and easier way to navigate the dictionary:

```
var allParams = Request.Query.Concat(Request.Form)
    .ToDictionary(p => p.Key, p => p.Value);
```