# 'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Params' and 'url'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, api, integration

Im working on my project Employee Site using asp.net.core , Im facing problem in PayPal Gateway integration  with Asp.net.core. I have created a controller called PaymentController taking help from https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/paypal-payment-gateway-integration-in-asp-net-mvc/ for ActionResult.

'HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Params' and
no accessible extension method 'Params' accepting a first argument of
type 'HttpRequest' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
an assembly reference?

at this line im facing error: string payerId = Request.Params["PayerID"];

at this line too with url:    string baseURI = Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + Request.Url.Authority
+ "/Home/PaymentWithPayPal?";

Comment: Is your controller at client or server?  A request has following 1) Client sends Request (POST) 2) Server receives Request (GET) 3) Server processes request 4) Server sends Response (POST) 5) Client receives Response (GET)

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['HttpRequest' does not contain a definition for 'Params'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47499391/httprequest-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-params)

Answer (score 0):

(in .NET CORE) Use:

```
var payerID = HttpContext.Request.Query["PayerID"].ToString()
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are calling the necessary class:

```cs
﻿using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication7.Models;
using PayPal.Api;
using PayPal.Util;
using PayPal.Api.OpenIdConnect;
```